# close bootstrap modal after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

Hi the initial state of `emailSent: false`. I want to close my modal after 5 seconds when the `this.state.emailSent: !== prevState.emailSent`. I've tried the following which closes as soon as `this.state.emailSent's value is set to true`. However what I want is for the modal to close after 5 secs. If I use `setTimeout()` then it closes the modal 5 secs after the modal has been rendered, when it is supposed to closes 5 secs after  `if (this.state.emailSent !== prevState.emailSent)`.

If you have Qs to why I have used jQuery in React is because this modal is rendered using bootstrap `<Button data-target="#open-modal" data-toggle="modal">`. It is not rendered using the show/hide state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

        if (this.state.emailSent !== prevState.emailSent) {

            $("#export-modal").modal('hide');

        }

    }
```

using setTimeout() but it ignores the if statement and closes modal 5 secs after being rendered on the page.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

        if (this.state.emailSent !== prevState.emailSent) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $("#export-modal").modal('hide');
            }, 5000);

        }

    }
```

Comment: It does not and can not ignore an IF statement. Your if statement is returning TRUE and hence the setTimeout() is run. Please debug step by step and verify that the IF statement is really working.

Comment: even if i just have `if(this.state.emailSent === true)`  as my check it doesn't work. Note initial state of `emailSent is false`.

Comment: @NawedKhan Hi, thanks for your comment. it was indeed that emailSent was true when the modal open that was causing the setTimeout to run.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use the function "setInterval".

I've setup an example in the snippet below.

```js
function checkStateChange() {
  console.log("check");
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready");
  
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    checkStateChange();
  }, 5000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In my example, I called the function inside the ready function, but you should probably call it whenever your modal opens, or you whenever the email/form is submitted.

So, after the chosen event, every 5 seconds, you will check the state, and if it's changed, you close the modal.

After the modal closes, you should probably stop the periodic checking by calling "clearInterval".

```
clearInterval(interval);
```